# SQL TableView with Filters, Export and Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, sql, dataview

I dont intend to offend anyone so I'll not call me neither a programmer or a dev..its more like a code-ctlr+c-ctrl+v.

I took a github open source platform - owsa - and im trying to implement it as a simple inventory management system.

I already achieved the easiest part.. connect a db, create and change a bunch of categories and i can present my products table and here his the main problem - for now.

After a week of searching and trying a lot of different solutions - `php` grid like apps, `angular` and other `javascript` solutions I cant find a way to simple present my data with filters over each `column`, `pages`, export to excel or pdf and with `CRUD` actions.

What would you guys would recommend to a simple - kind of - solution ?

I can share code if needed.

Comment: Always share you code, because without it, its hard to tell what problems your facing.

Comment: next time i'll share in order to allow you guys to help me but since this was a looking-for-solution quest i thought it shouldnt be needed

Comment: If you want a solution, you should ask a crystal clear question. Right now you ask quite a lot. You need a solution for filtering you columns, option to export pdf and you want CRUD action. Instead of asking for everything at ones, you could start asking how to filter a column using owsa. A link to the github project would help to fix your problem. Then go on to question 2, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **highly** recommend you to look into DataTables, there's a free (and paid/pro) jQuery extension for it that's compatible and it's quite basic, but it's an overpowered library with a ton of features.

https://datatables.net/

It takes care of pagination, searching, filtering, sorting, showing ascending/descending by column, it's responsive for mobile and smaller displays, etc...

It has a low barrier of entry, as it's easy to get started with it. You could get lost with the ton of customization available once you get in their documentation and forums, but I'm sure it will cover all of your needs and even more (such as an easily available print/pdf/csv export button)

Comment: thanks m8. i l take a look.